Postgresql- trigger to insert and then to truncate table
I'm using a transition table to import rows in a source table after collecting data with Qfield on the transition table.
This function works well to import rows:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shema.function_name()
    RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO shema.source_table (field1, field2, field3)
    VALUES(NEW.*);

    RETURN new;
END; $BODY$;

Here is the trigger (inside the transition table)
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT
    ON shema.transition_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION shema.function_name();

It's working well but now I want to truncate the transition_table after the import. My goal is to achieve these two steps:

export rows from transition_table to source_table
delete all rows in transition_table

So I'll be able to go back to the field with my application, collect some new data in the empty transition_table and do it again.
I've tried many things but it's a fail. I'm a beginner with trigger.

Huh? The trigger cannot work, and truncating a table after you imported something doesn't make much sense.

@LaurenzAlbe I'm grasping for straws but my guess is it might if there are other triggers doing something with it beforehand, and/or they're testing something else and that's their /dev/null.

Are you actually doing anything in the transition table to change the data?


Use a per-statement trigger so that it just fires once for each insert, not for each incoming row. REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newtab also lets you move all those rows at once as if they were in a special table.

Use an unqualified delete to wipe the table the trigger is attached to. It has the same effect as truncate:

TRUNCATE quickly removes all rows from a set of tables. It has the same effect as an unqualified DELETE

but unlike truncate, you can use it there without a problem.


demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shema.function_name()
    RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO shema.source_table(field1, field2, field3)TABLE newtab;
    --`truncate` isn't allowed for `transition_table` in this context
    --use unqualified `delete` instead
    DELETE FROM shema.transition_table;
    
    RETURN null;
END; $BODY$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT
    ON shema.transition_table
    REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newtab
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION shema.function_name();


What a quick answer :)

First, I'm sorry you're right it was my re-transcription mistake, my real function is not looping. Actually it is : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shema.function_name()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
shema.source_table (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES(NEW.*);
       RETURN new;

END;
$BODY$;

I changed my question. sorry for the mistake.

@fg13 You first said you want to truncate transition_table after importing data. In the edit you added that you want to wipe source_table. Which one do you want to wipe then, both. If you want to 1. insert them into transition_table. 2. insert them to source_table 3. wipe transition_table, here's a demo: you can use statement-level trigger with an unqualified delete in in it (as I already showed above).

I want to truncate transition_table! I just re-re-re_edited my question...

@fg13 I've added an example. Is that what you're trying to do?

I'm looking at it. thank you!! I'll answer you soon

I'm trying to understand what is the "newtab"

In row-level triggers there's the special pseudo-record NEW, where you can inspect all fields of incoming row. In statement-level triggers you define a similar thing when attaching the trigger (REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newtab) and that thing holds all rows the whole statement produced. This means if you insert 1000 rows, it doesn't fire 1000 inserts and 1000 deletes for each of them, it just fires once, sees the whole thing, does one big insert, one big delete, and that's it. It's just way more effective.

It's working! I've got a lot to learn about triggers to fully understand your solution but... thank you!

Should I copy your solution ? So it'll be easier to find for others users.

What do you mean, copy where? If it solved the problem, you just mark it.

Please see What should I do when someone answers my question?
